# 8PSK modulation does not work

Tags: modulation, gnuradio

I implemented a data transfer system using two tutorials: [Guided Tutorial PSK Demodulation](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Guided_Tutorial_PSK_Demodulation) and [Packet Communications](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php?title=Packet_Communications). After that, I decided to change QPSK to 8PSK.
My scheme: [image]
Constellation Sink: [image]
For some reason, the Costas loop turns the constellation, although this should not be. If I put the Order = 7 value in the block, then the constellation will fall into place, although judging by the documentation, this value is not correct.
Setting up Constellation Rect. Object: [image]

Constellation Points: **[0+1j, 0.707+0.707j, 1+0j, -0.707+0.707j, -1+0j, -0.707-0.707j, 0 - 1j, 0.707-0.707j]**
Maybe it's all about the Real and imaginary sectors?
It is also not possible to synchronize characters using Delay.

**As a result, my output file is empty.**

What could be the problem and what points am I missing?